# how to get the wordID and send it to another php file

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

I have a table that third column of it is checkboxe, and first two columns of it come from database
I want to send the wordID of words that checked:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words");
    echo "<table border='1'>
       <tr>
          <th>word</th>
          <th>meaning</th>
          <th>checking</th>
        </tr>";
                         while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                      {
                                      echo "<tr>";
                                      echo "<td>" . $row['word'] . "</td>";
                                       $idd= $row['id'] ;
                                      echo "<td>". "<div class='hiding' style='display:none'>".$row['meaning']."</div>"."</td>";
                                      echo "<td>";
                                     echo "<input class=\"box\" name=\"$idd\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\"> ";
                                      echo "</td>";
                                      echo "</tr>";

                                      }
      echo "</table>";
```

and in my function I have this:

```
 function feedback(){
            var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
            for(var j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++){
                if(boxes[j].checked) {

                      assign=1;
                }
                else{
                      assign=0;

                }

                $.ajax({
                    url: "assigner.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { wordid: wordid, assign: assign}
                }).done(function( e ) {
                    /*alert( "word was saved" + e );*/
                });
            }
        }
```

I dont know how can I get WordId from the first part and use it in second part that I said

Comment: what do you mean? the alert part? just use `wordid` again there, it's valid until the `for` loop reiterates

Comment: Rather nasty...if you have 50 checkboxes, you're going to be doing 50 ajax calls. There's much better ways of doing such things...

Answer (score 0):

Just put another form element outside of the table, like:

```
<input type="hidden" value="[id]" name="wordid_name" id="worid_id" class="wordid_class">
```

You only have to replace [id] with the id of the row, then on Javascript you can call the attribute you prefer:

```
var wordid= document.getElementsByClassName('worid_class').value;
var wordid= document.getElementsById('worid_id').value;
var wordid= document.getElementsByName('worid_name').value;
```

Can make it outside for structure, just below var boxex.

I recommend you to create an Javascript object with the values of the checkboxes and then call just 1 time to Ajax.

Hope it helps you.